# Using JS forEach to convert multi-dimensional array to html table

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, undefined

I have very little experience with Javascript arrays. I have a complex enough requirement that I need to put my data into an array and then generate an HTML table. In this example, I have a multi-dimensional array here for a Leaderboard where each value is an array of the team's scores.

I've nested a forEach within a forEach to construct the rows and cells. However, I keep getting two 'undefined' responses at the top, one for each team. I think it has something to do with the thisValue part of the forEach method, but I can't stop it or replace it.

I'm sure this is not the proper way to set this up, but if it's possible to get this working with a minor tweak for now, it would be ideal. See images. Any help is appreciated!

```
leaderBoard.forEach(row);

function row(value,index,array)
{
    document.write('<tr>' + value.forEach(cell) + '</tr>');
}

function cell(value,index,array)
{
    document.write('<td>' + value + '</td>');
}
```

[image]

When I remove the reference to the cell function from the row function, it returns the arrays and the 'undefinedundefined' disappears. Note below that I removed '.forEach(cell)' and added the data tags.

```
function row(value,index,array)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
}
```

[Table without undefined at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDMLe.png)

Comment: You're terminating your row with a `</td>`, not a `</tr>`

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: It wasn't the <td> tag, I fixed that and it's still the same output.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the output you currently have?

Comment: The 'undefinedundefined' at the top of the table. It appears to be created within the row function.

Comment: Are you sure? because it would appear to be output before the header...

Comment: I'm going to add an image of what returns when I remove the nested function.

Comment: Please don't use images. Copy and paste the source HTML instead.

Comment: please show more, how is your array ? how do you call your function? ...

Comment: General comment: when building up elements a bit at a time, it's better to accumulate the HTML into a variable (html += "more stuff") as you go along, and then add it all at once (document.write(html);).  Furthermore, document.write isn't the best way (usually), but rather adding DOM elements using "createElement" etc., or modifying ("element.innerHTML = html;") an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will accomplish what you want

```
leaderBoard.forEach(function (row) {
  row.forEach(function (cell) {
      document.write('<tr><td>' + cell + '</td></tr>');
    });
});
```

Your attempt removing the reference to the cell function was close. The problem was that you were writing your entire row into 1 cell

```
//value = [AM, 90, 76, 67, 233]
function row(value,index,array)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
}
```